# What file path would I use with ng-include?

Tags: html, angularjs, filepath, partials, angularjs-ng-include

My angular project's path is like this

```
web
    server.py ##flask server program
    app
        static
            app.js
            controllers.js
            etc...
        templates
            index.html
            home.html
```

index.html

```
<!-- this didn't work -->
<ng-include src="templates/home.html"><ng-include>

<!-- nor did this -->
<ng-include src="home.html"></ng-include>
```

home.html

```
<h1> home! </h1>
```

Except I don't see the partial (home.html) in my output.

Anyone see my mistake?

Comment: You don't pass a file path. You pass the URL of the partial you want to include. Just like you would in a `<a href="...">` or in a `<img src="...">`. So, look at what the URL is in the address bar, and use a relative or (better) absolute path to the partial you want to load.

Comment: "use a relative or (better) absolute path" > Why would it be better to use an absolute path? To me it looks like we're aren't completely sure what's happening there. I guess it should be better to use a relative path, because it's more reusable.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The src attribute of ng-include expects a string. Either you pass a scope variable, or pass string directly.

```
<ng-include src=" 'templates/home.html' "></ng-include>
```