# What's the right way to use ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm beginner on Angular.js and am having some problems with the directive `ng-include`.

I want to display contents of `header.html` inside `index.html`

Well, here's my tree example:

```
myapp
.    public
.    .     lib
.    .     .  angular.js
.    .     .  
.    header.html
.    index.html
```

Header.html code:

```
<h1>Hello Angular</h1>
```

Index.html code:

```
<html ng-app>
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="public/lib/angular.js"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body>  
    <ng-include src="'header.html'"></ng-include> 
  </body>   
</html>
```

When i run `index.html`, i have something like this:

```
<!-- ngInclude: undefined -->
```

Comment: the easiest way to check you're input it right or wrong, make an anchor with `href="header.html"`, then see the result there. I don't know how you started your app, so I cannot sure anything.

Comment: This should work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499228/angular-ng-include-what-file-path-would-i-use. There's something happening that's not shown in your question.

Comment: Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943471/angularjs-ng-include)

Comment: How are you accessing `index.html` ? can you post the url ?

Comment: Also you almost certainly want to be using a directive here, not an include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you accessing the app through a web server or by accessing the file through `file://` protocol? In the latter case it won't work due to browser's security restrictions. The solution would be to install Apache or Nginx and access the app through something like `http://localhost/myapp/index.html`.

Comment: I'm looking for an alternative that does not need to use a web server or ajax to import HTML files but it seems that will not be possible

Comment: You could use inline template by using [the script directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script). You can see an example at the bottom of the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's an `ng-include` tag to include other templates. We usually do it this way

```
<div ng-include src="'header.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Custom elements are a valid option (with a few IE caveats).

Comment: also, if you do it this way it should be <div ng-include="'header.html'"></div> ...only use src= if you're using the ng-include tag.